# Android Locale : Configure locale for canadian english and normal english

Tags: android, localization, locale, mobility

In a multi-language app, when i am using default language(English) it picks up the strings.xml from the default (res/values) folder. Whereas for canadian english also it uses from the same folder(res/values). As per android standard, It has to pick up from the corresponding folder(res/values-en-rCA).

I dont know where i am going wrong. Will it take according to the device language ?

Locale code used :

English - en

English/Canada - en_CA

Comment: I'm offended that you think Canadian English is abnormal

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to set the locale in order to load the proper resources.


 DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
 Locale locale = new Locale("en_CA");
 configuration.locale = locale;
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 res.updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

Comment: I am using the same code only. Even if i set like that also. The locale is converting the code(en_CA) to lowercase like this en_ca. I have many activities. I can't change in all those classes. Is there any other way ?

Comment: try changing Locale locale = new Locale("en_CA");  to Locale locale = Locale.CANADA;

Comment: I have tried that long back. It works. But i have used the same piece of code in around 50 places in my code. So i have to replace all. Is there any other way ? and i want to know why the locale is always converting to lowercase(en_CA to en_ca)

Comment: You need to avoid repeating code within your app that is not healthy for the system and you look now you must change a lot of places to fix it. You can create a class like Util class and implement it so call that wherever you want to change the locale. This apply for other stuff you can have on your app.

Comment: Yes i have done it using a util class but i want to know why the locale is always converting the locale code to lowercase itself (en_CA to en_ca).  When we assign a locale code to a new locale object !!! We can't restrict it why ?.

Comment: Did you try using Locale locale = Locale.CANADA??

Comment: I tried Locale locale = new Locale("en").CANADA. It works but when i assign the same object to the newly created Locale object like this (Locale newLocale = locale); Its converting that locale in lowercase. Did you get my point ?

Comment: Can you share some code I can see what are you doing?